# How to continuously call python file with argument parsing

Tags: python, operating-system, pipeline

I am trying to build a basic pipeline for a workflow I have. Here is what I have so far:

```
def parse_all_files():
    import os
    import glob

    PATH = '{}{}'.format(os.getcwd(), '/data/payment_files/new/*.csv')
    COMMAND = 'python paypal_post_process.py -a %PAYPAL_KEY% %PAYPAL_SECRET% -e live -p {}'

    new_files = glob.glob(PATH)

    for file in new_files[5:]:
        os.system(COMMAND.format(file))
```

This is wrapped inside of a bigger pipeline file, but my objective is to run this `paypal_post_processing` with these arguments being passed dynamically. Firstly, is there a better practice for this?  I feel like there should be.  Second, when I run this, it all works, however the loop never seems to break for some reason. I can't get the program to stop executing.

Any tips? Thanks!

Comment: Use the `subprocess` module, not `os.system`.